# Redshift pg_automv schema. Is it generic?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm working on customer's database. It has multiple schemas. One of the schemas called pg_automv and inside it I have only entities like (changed some numbers with letters):

```
mv_tbl__auto_mv_44xxx49x__0,
mv_tbl__auto_mv_44aaa78a__0,
mv_tbl__auto_mv_4dddd688d__0
```

My theory is that automatically refreshed materialized views are stored in this schema, but I can't find any proof.
I don't think the customer created this schema by himself. Is this a generic schema?
The information about automated materialized views from following link doesn't prove my theory.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/materialized-view-auto-mv.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you correctly pointed out the new schema (`pg_automv`) is reserved for Automatic Materialized Views that are being created, refreshed and maintained in the background after carefully monitoring cluster's workload. The documentation will get updated soon to better explain this.

For a more detailed example of Auto MVs please refer to this recent blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimize-your-amazon-redshift-query-performance-with-automated-materialized-views/

Comment: So when do us common folk get to magically create non schema bound materialized views?